# List details of all directories and sub-directories only

Tags: linux, recursion, ls

Using the following works to show details of current directories.

```
> ls -ld *
```

Using the following works to show details of all directories and files in current location and sub-directories too.

```
> ls -lR *
```

But if I only wanted to view the details of only the current directories and only sub-directories, the following doesn't work.

```
> ls -lRd *
```

Why does -lR work and -ld work but not a combination of -lRd?

Is there an easy way to obtain this information?

Comment: I guess you are looking for `find . -exec ls -ld {} \;`, but perhaps you want `find . -maxdepth 1 -exec ls -ld {} \;`

Comment: But `find . -exec ls -ld {} +` might be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want something like:

```
find . -type d -exec ls -ld {} +
```

but it's not really clear to me what you mean when you say that `ls -lr *` works.  Using `*` just expands to all names in the current directory, and `-r` just changes the order in which things are printed.  `ls -lrd *` simply lists stats for all the entries in the current directory, and nothing is shown for the subdirectories because you've restricted the output with `-d`.

Comment: Works great, thanks.  Originally I was try to list details (-l) of only directories (-d) and to do it recursively (-r) but guess that combination becomes restricted?

Comment: `-r` does not mean "recursive".  It sorts the names in reverse order.

Comment: My bad. I did mean to type -R, not -r.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do something like this:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ ls -ld **/
```

Having the option `globstar` set by default in your rc-files does not harm. The same accounts for `extglob`. `globstar` enables the recursive glob `**` and `extglob` enables various other useful glob-expressions.